# Any way to make partitioning tools see kpartx-created devices?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, dd, device-mapper

I have a `dd`'ed disk image file with me.

I can use a tool like `kpartx` to create a device-mapper device from this disk image file.

But partitioning programs like `gparted` and `fdisk` don't list my mapped device!

Is there any way to make `gparted` (or an equivalent program - graphical or console) list my mapped device and its constituent partitions and detailed information about these partitions?

PS: Is this a case of missing feature from these tools, or is it that providing this feature is fundamentally not possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but I am not sure if it makes sense.

Partitioning tools only care about the whole-disk device, because they read the partition table directly from the relevant disk sectors. They don't need per-partition devices to exist. This means that a basic loop device made with `losetup` is enough, and if a tool doesn't see it, you can just manually run `fdisk /dev/loop0` or something.

(If a *whole-disk* device is in `/dev/mapper/`, it's not hard to make those tools see it, although it usually involves editing a few lines of the source code... running `fdisk /dev/mapper/bleh` is often easier.)

---

Also note that recent kernels support `losetup --partscan` which removes the need to use device-mapper for this.

Comment: I definitely learned something from your answer, so thanks. But what do you mean by "per-partition device"? I tend to think that a whole-disk device would be something like my disk image file `losetup`'ed, so, then, shouldn't partitioning tools care about it?

Comment: @Harry: If `sda` or `loop0` represent the entire disk (or image), then `sda1` or `loop0p1` represent the first partition, `sda2` or `loop0p2` represent the second partition, and so on. Reading one of those "partition" devices will only give you the partition's contents.

Comment: @Harry: And no, partitioning tools don't always need the per-partition devices, since they know the partition table's contents, where each partition starts and ends, and can just find the partition data that way. ⫽ Note that there are two kinds of partitioning tools: those which actually *access* the data inside partitions, and those that don't. GParted is in the former group, because it also lets you move and resize filesystems inside those partitions. Meanwhile, fdisk and parted are in the latter – they edit *only* the parttable, and don't care about the data in partitions themselves at all.

Comment: @Harry: This means that GParted, fdisk and parted can do their main task (i.e. listing partitions, adding or deleting them) by just reading/writing `sda` or `loop0`. ⫽ However, for *resizing* a filesystem, the external tools that GParted uses (e.g. `resize2fs` or `ntfsresize`) *do* need to be given a "partition" device (`sda2` or `loop0p2`).

Comment: Ok, I think you're calling a "partition" as a "per-partition device", whereas I tend to call it a "partition" and the disk image file as a "device". Your info on the partitioning tool classification was really helpful!

Comment: Pretty much everything in `/dev` is called a "device".

Answer (score 3):

**Just create temporary hardlink** after running `kpartx -a ...`:

```
sudo ln /dev/loop0 /dev/mapper/loop0
```

And then run gparted as usual (it will properly operate `/dev/mapper/loop0p*`):

```
sudo gparted /dev/mapper/loop0
```

Don't forget to remove link when its not needed anymore.

Comment: Amazing.  This just helped me use gparted to resize a 4GB Raspian image to fill a 16GB SD card.  Thanks!

Comment: You have to be careful though. After they change partition boundaries or add or remove partitions, partitioning tools run `partprobe` or something similar to update special files associated with partitions. **This doesn't update your `/dev/mapper/*` files, they still point to the same parts of the whole image!** If a tool needs these files (`gparted` does) then it's wise to apply operations one at a time, destroying and rebuilding files created by `kpartx` after each operation so the next one sees coherent data.

Answer (score 0):

After 3.5 years I have another solution on that :)

if you are not concerned about using kpartx and I am correct suggesting that your target is to operate partitions on a disk image represented as an ordinary file, here is an alternative workflow without kpartx and symlinking (that's why it's posted as a separate answer):

1. **`sudo losetup --find --show ./somedrive.img`**

   Attach a loop device for the whole file `./somedrive.img`; `--find` is to ask `losetup` to look for free device automatically; and `--show` is to print the device has been used. For example, consider the chosen device is `/dev/loop5`.
2. **`sudo partx --update /dev/loop5`**

   Tell the Linux kernel to rescan partitions inside `/dev/loop5`. In case of success it will not produce any output, so check out `ls -al /dev/loop5*` to see what appears.
3. **Do whatever you need, like `sudo gparted /dev/loop5`**

   At this point you should be able to properly operate `/dev/loop5p*`.
4. **`sudo partx --delete /dev/loop5`**

   Release the partition mappings.
5. **`sudo losetup --detach /dev/loop5`**

   Finally, release loop device.

**P.S.** If you are the Proud Owner™ of `util-linux` package with version v2.21 or higher, you can request both loop device attachment and a partition rescan in one shot: `sudo losetup --find --show --partscan ./somedrive.img` and should not meet the problem with gparted-like utils at all.